# Is it safe to turn off Jackrabbit's indexing feature?

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

We only use Jackrabbit for storing files, which we are later retrieving using their full path or UUID. Is it safe to turn off the Jackrabbit index in this case?

What about Jackrabbit XPath queries, do they use the fulltext index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only access the nodes using the path and the UUID (identifier), you can safely turn of the Lucene index.

The XPath queries do need to the Lucene index.

To reduce the overhead of maintaining the Lucene index, you could use a [custom index configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Search#Search_Configuration), and specially [index rules](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration) to only index certain properties.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. So if we wanted to use XPath queries, we could create a custom index configuration to just index the properties we want to query for, e.g. just the meta data and not the content of the stored files, right?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I have never done that myself so far, so I don't know all the details however.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer!